# Button for update function not working laravel 8 (CRUD)

Tags: laravel-8, php-7.4

I'm new to laravel 8. I try to make an update function controller when user already edit their data and store it in database. I try to click submit button and it's not working without any reason when i try to inspect at chrome. So i try another way which is comment the $request->validate and it's only change for name data while organisation_id leave blank and return to NULL. I wonder do we need to always validate the data in update function ?

Here is my Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
 $record = User::find($id);
 $org = Organisation::all();
 $t = Organisation::pluck("name");

 return view ('user.edit',compact('record','org','t'));
 }

public function edit_store(Request $request, $id)
{
  $request->validate([
  'name' => 'required',
  'organisation_id' => 'required',
  ]
  );

 $record= User::find($id);
 $record->name = $request->name;
 $record->organisation_id = $request->organisation_id;
 $record->save();

 return redirect ('user')->with('success', 'Thank you');
 }
```

Here is my edit blade

```
 <div class="card">
 <div class="card-body">
 <form action="{{route('user_edit_store1', $record->id)}}" method="POST">
  @csrf

 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $record->id }}">

 <div class="form-group row">
 <label for="name"
 class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <input id="name" type="text"
 class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name"
 value="{{ old('name') ? old('name') : $record->name }}" 
 </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group row">
<label for="organisation_id"
 class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Organisation') }}</label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'user_store']) !!}
 {!! Form::select('id', $t, 'id',  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row mb-0">
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4"> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
  {{ __('Save') }} 
 </button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Routes

```
Route::get('user_edit/{id}',[UserController::class,'edit'])->name('user_edit');
Route::post('user_edit_store/{user}',[UserController::class,'edit_store'])->name('user_edit_store1');
```

Model user.php

```
protected $fillable = [
'name',
'organisation_id',
];
```

Comment: There are several problems in the code you've shown.  1) You have 2 nested `<form>`s, (though only one of them is closed).  That is invalid and will not work.  2) The first form action (`route('user_edit_store1', $record->id)`) uses [the wrong syntax for specifying a route parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes).  3) `Form::select('id'...` creates a `<select>` with name `id`, but your validation and controller method are looking for a field named `organisation_id`.

Comment: 4) Your edit view does not [show validation errors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `<select>` that you're creating with the `Form::select` form helper will have name of 'id' instead of 'organisation_id' which will result in a validation fail.